# Dynamic allocation of classes

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I have a question about object array allocation,
the problem is this:
I have a class called person :

```
class Person {
    char* name;
    int ID;


public:
    Person(char* name = NULL, int ID = 0) :name(name), ID(ID) {};
}
```

and I'm trying to make an array of persons like so:

```
Person *pArr = new Person[size];
```

and after that I extract the data from a file (char* for string and int for ID)
and I use for loop and the constructors to place the persons inside the loop like so:

```
for (int j = 0; j < size3; j++) {
pArr[j] = Person(Name, id);
}
```

after I finish my program I want to use the Destructor and free the allocated string that's stored inside the char* name, but when I add the Destructor it gets triggered right after the loops ends,
every Person that's being created is destroyed immediately,
I know its possible to make an array of pointers and allocated the person aswell, but in this assignment I'm suppose to do it like this, 
is there a right way to do it without triggering the destructor right away?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but if you're looking for dynamic array allocation, why not use a [vector?](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Comment: Use `std::vector` and `std::string` instead of arrays and your life will be much easier.

Comment: There are very few reasons for having a `char *`  as a member of a class. Use a `std::string`.

Comment: You probably need to define an assignment operator for your class. Follow the [Rule of 3 and 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))

Comment: `pArr[j] = Person(Name, id);` creates a temporary `Person` object, copies its value to `pArr[j]`, then destroys the temporary `Person` object.

Comment: @ melpomene The thing is when I dont add the destructor I use the array later in the code and it works fine, just when I add the delete in the destructor it triggers it right away

Comment: @JeJo the thing is I dont know how many classes to make it varies, should I just build default constructors and then set it?

Comment: @Barmar this is a school project we are not allowed to use strings or vectors.

Comment: @AlexAlex Then you need to follow the rule of 3 and 5.

Comment: I would also suggest using `std::unique_ptr`n in conjunction with what others have said about `std::vector` and `std::string`. That way you won't have to manually free anything.

Comment: @samuelnj since the OP is not allowed to use `std::string` or `std::vector`, he's likely not allowed to use `std::unique_ptr` either.

Comment: @AlexAlex *This is a school project we are not allowed to use strings or vectors.* -- I don't understand why these "schools" just not have you create your own string and vector classes that you can use in this and future projects, if they insist on these silly restrictions.  These rounabout silly ways of using `char *` members in `Person` objects teaches nothing -- at least when given the assignment to actually create a string or vector class, you learn what others have told you in the comments (rule of 3, 5).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On this line:

```
pArr[j] = Person(Name, id);
```

You are creating a *temporary* `Person` object, and then assigning it to the `pArr[j]` object.  `Person` has no explicit copy assignment operator defined, so the compiler auto-generates one for you, which simply performs a member-by-member copy of values from one object to another.

When the temporary goes out of scope on the `;`, it is automatically destroyed.  The compiler-generated assignment operator copied the `name` pointer as-is to the `pArr[j]` object, so if `Person` has a destructor that frees its `name`, the `pArr[j]` object will be left with a dangling `name` pointer to freed memory.

Your `Person` class is not following the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)):

> The rule of three (also known as the Law of The Big Three or The Big Three) is a rule of thumb in C++ (prior to C++11) that claims that if a class defines one (or more) of the following it should probably explicitly define all three:
>
> - destructor
> - copy constructor
> - copy assignment operator

Since you want `Person` to have a destructor that frees `name`, it also needs a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator so it can make copies of `name` for the destructor to free, eg:

```
class Person
{
    char* name;
    int id;

public:
    Person(const char* Name = NULL, int ID = 0)
        : name(new char[std::strlen(Name)+1]), id(ID)
    {
        std::strcpy(name, Name);
    }

    Person(const Person &src)
        : name(new char[std::strlen(src.name)+1]), id(src.id)
    {
        std::strcpy(name, src.name);
    }

    ~Person()
    {
        delete[] name;
    }

    Person& operator=(const Person &rhs)
    {
        if (&rhs != this)
        {
            Person tmp(rhs);

            //std::swap(tmp.name, name);
            char *p = tmp.name;
            tmp.name = name;
            name = p;

            id = tmp.id;
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Now, back on this line:

```
pArr[j] = Person(Name, id);
```

The temporary will be copied to `pArr[j]` safely and properly.  Just note that if you dynamically allocated `Name` beforehand, you will now have to free it afterwards, since `Person` makes its own internal copy.

---

If you can change `char*` to `std::string`, then you don't have to worry about the compiler making default copies, since `std::string` is compliant with the Rule of Three and will be copied properly:

```
class Person
{
    std::string name;
    int id;

public:
    Person(const std::string &name = std::string(), int ID = 0)
        : name(name), id(ID)
    {
    }

    // no explicit copy constructor, destructor, or
    // assignment operator is needed, as compiler-generated
    // defaults will suffice...
};
```

Comment: Hi, I did the operator like you suggested, allocated the new memory but still after leaving the loop it triggers the destructor right away that deletes my name..

Comment: @AlexAlex as it should be, since the loop is creating temporary `Person` objects that go out of scope right away after each assignment. You can't avoid that. But, by giving each instance of `Person` it's own copy of the `name` data, it doesn't matter anymore that temporary objects are being destroyed. Only the temp's destructor is called, so only the temp's data is freed. Everyone else's data is preserved due to extra copies of the data being allocated. You weren't doing that originally