# C++ Linker error LNK 2019 unresolved external symbol referenced in function

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I am trying to implement a smart class following the article

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15351/Implementing-a-simple-smart-pointer-in-c

I have a class called **Person**.

```
class Person
{
    private:
        char* name;
        int age;
    public:
        Person();
        Person(const char* pName, int pAge);
        ~Person();
        void Display();
};
```

**Person.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Person.h"

Person::Person() : name(nullptr), age(0)
{}

Person::Person(const char* pName, int pAge) 
{
      name = new char[std::strlen(pName) + 1];
      std::strcpy(name, pName);
      age = pAge;
}

Person::~Person()
{}

void Person::Display()
{
     std::cout << "Name is " << name << " and age is " << age << std::endl;
}
```

**ReferenceCount.h**

```
#pragma once
class ReferenceCount
{
    private:
         int count;
    public:
        ReferenceCount();
        ~ReferenceCount();
        void AddRef();
        void DelRef();
```

};

**ReferenceCount.cpp**

```
#include "ReferenceCount.h"

ReferenceCount::ReferenceCount() : count(0)
{}

ReferenceCount::~ReferenceCount()
{}

void ReferenceCount::AddRef()
{
     count++;
}

void ReferenceCount::DelRef()
{
    count--;
}
```

**SmartClass.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "ReferenceCount.h"

template <typename T> class SmartClass
{
   private:
       T* pData;
       ReferenceCount* rc;
   public:
       SmartClass();
       SmartClass(T* data);
       SmartClass(const SmartClass<T>& sp); // copy constructor
      ~SmartClass();
      T& operator*();
      T* operator->();
      SmartClass<T>& operator=(const SmartClass<T>& sp); // copy assignment operator
};
```

**SmartClass.cpp**

```
#include "SmartClass.h"

template <typename T>
SmartClass<T>::SmartClass() : rc(0)
{
    rc = new ReferenceCount();
    rc->AddRef();
}

template <typename T> 
SmartClass<T>::SmartClass(T* data) : pData(data), rc(0)
{
   rc = new ReferenceCount();
   rc->AddRef();
}

template<typename T>
SmartClass<T>::SmartClass(const SmartClass<T>& sp)  // copy constructor
{
  this->pData = sp.pData;
  this->rc = sp.rc;
}

template <typename T>
SmartClass<T>::~SmartClass()
{
  if (rc->DelRef() == 0) 
  {
    delete pData;
    delete rc;
  }
}

template <typename T>
T& SmartClass<T>::operator*()
{
  return *pdata;
}

template<typename T>
T* SmartClass<T>::operator->()
{
  return pData;
}

template <typename T>
SmartClass<T>& SmartClass<T>::operator=(const SmartClass<T>& sp)
{
  if (this != &sp)
  {
     if (rc->DelRef() == 0)
     {
        delete pData;
        delete rc;
     }

     pData = sp.pData;
     rc = sp.rc;
    rc->AddRef();
 }
    return *this;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Person.h"
#include "SmartClass.h"

int main()
{
    SmartClass<Person> p(new Person("Scott", 25));
    return 0;
}
```

I got the following linker errors when I build the program using Visual Studio 2017.

> LNK2019    unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall SmartClass::SmartClass(class Person *)" (??0?$SmartClass@VPerson@@@@QAE@PAVPerson@@@Z) referenced in function _main
>
> LNK2019    unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall SmartClass::~SmartClass(void)" (??1?$SmartClass@VPerson@@@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main

What did I do wrong in this code? Can you please help me to correct it?

Thank you.

Comment: `Person* pt = new Person("Scott, 25");` should be `Person* pt = new Person("Scott", 25);` and you need to either follow Rule of 3(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) or use `std::string` instead of `char* name;`

Comment: Typo: you missed a close quote in the constructor call.

Comment: Hello All,
I corrected the code regarding double quote but still got the same error.

Comment: @userfirst785935 You have your init constructor wrong. See this possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768499/dynamic-allocation-of-classes/50768708#50768708

Comment: You can not use string literal to initialize variable of type pointer to non-const char. String literals yield an array of const chars. So you should (1) use `std::string` instead of raw pointer for `name` field (2) accept `char const * pName` as a constructor argument.

Comment: Standard mistake, templates do not have external linkage.  You need to get rid of SmartClass.cpp and move the code for the template functions into SmartClass.h.  Now the compiler can generate the flavors of them that are specific to Person.

Answer (score 0):

There are two constructor,one no argument,the other has two arguments.If you want to call the second constructor,you have to give two arguments as "Person *pt = new Person("Scott", 25)".